# Persist Session State to a DB Table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, persistence

Using ASP .Net C# 3.5 running on IIS 6 and a SQL Server 2005 backend.

I'm implementing a complex multi-step/multi-purpose web form based Intranet web application which has many controls and uses form authentication.  The steps are very dynamic with panels and controls presented to or hidden from users according to user selections made in various steps.

The form is intense and time consuming for users and per mandate that won't change.

I'm attempting to insure the user doesn't get frustrated if their session is interrupted for any reason by insuring the completed steps will be restored when they return to the application.

Using an HTTPModule/HTTPHandler called FormStateKeeper (http://fsk.codeplex.com/) does exactly this for instances where the user's authentication times out.

Since FormStateKeeper works well for authentication time outs, I've tried to extend/modify it by creating a storage provider that stores the serialized form state in a DB table as a varbinary instead of in the runtime cache which is FormStateKeeper's default.  This appears to work i.e. the form when deserialized and reconstituted into the intermediate page looks perfect and identical to one stored in a runtime cache.

Anyway, my attempts to use FormStateKeeper using DB storage haven't been successful.

I realize I could just serialize the form but I'd like to get the viewstate/control state also since the entire page/app is very dynamic with controls/panels hidden/disabled, step indication graphics etc.

I have no problem serializing/deserializing and storing the above but am a bit lost on the best approach to restore a web page to it's saved state for the user when they log back into the application i.e. generate a postback from an intermediate virtual page etc..

Info, suggestions and examples would be much appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net has its own built in SQL Server [session state manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) that you can easily configure for your application.

If you save all of your form variables into the session (you could even have an AJAX process running behind the scenes to update the session items every minute or so to track form variables as they are being added.

Here are a couple of articles to help get started:

- [HOW TO: Configure ASP.NET for
  Persistent SQL Server Session State
  Management](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311209/EN-US/)
- [HOW TO: Configure SQL
  Server to Store ASP.NET Session
  State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Comment: Dillie-O - Thanks for your suggestion. I looked at using the ASP .Net SQL session state.  I didn't think the session would be available to a user that say returned to log in after a couple of days.  Would SQL session state work in this fasion?  Thanks Steve

Comment: @Steve: Using the custom database configuration or even the custom server mode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) I believe you could track a UserId with the session state, or match a UserId to a SessionId for retrieval at a future date. I haven't looked into this process, but it seems feasible to me.

Comment: Dillie-O - I'll have to take another look at that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak from experience as I have worked on *serious* ASP.NET/MVC web sites (e.g. .5 million unique visitors and 11 million visits per month, etc.)...
My recommendation is to not try to save the state of the actual widgets on the page, rather save the user’s data entry into a staging repository (you custom session provider, or whatever) with enough metadata about the *state* of the user within the process*). For example, if I were coding a long process insurance coverage application (which I have):

Real data: name, phone, gender, dependants, created date, modified date, application status = ‘in progress’, etc...

Metadata: last step completed = 3, etc...

Ensure you metadata is application version resilient…for example, if user comes in and completes 5 of 10 steps on day 1 and on day 2 the app is changes to only have 4 steps, what happens for the returing user: error (you should be fired if you answer this); heuristics on completed data (best option), static mapping of old to new (iffy). Then again, I have always found more success when a user can be transient within a process until ultimate submission time.

My two cents.

Comment: D.P. - Thanks for pointing out the application version issue - That's a major consideration.  In my previous attempts to modify FormStateKeeper to use a SQL table to store the form state I used a column with the form state version to track compatibility of the restore with current version to avoid this issue. i.e. if the current form state (modified) application didn't match the stored user's version the restore wouldn't happen. Great observation - thank you.  Steve